# Weakly convergence in C(X) for metric compact spaces

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space.
Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions in $C(X)$. Show that if $f_n$ converges to $0$ weakly then $|f_n|$ converges to $0$ weakly.
Actually, I need to show then $f_n$ converges to $0$ weakly iff $\sup ||f_n||$ is bounded (uniform norm) and $f_n$ converges to $0$ pointwise.
But I can show the direction: weakly convergence implies $\sup$ norm is bounded by the first argument.
I'm familiar with Reisz Representation Theorem.

Thank you in advance.